# Proving that in an acute $\Delta$, the angle bisector is between the median and altitude

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have $\Delta XYZ$ that is an acute triangle where $YA$ is its median, $YB$ is the $\angle Y$ bisector, and $YC$ is the altitude where points $A,B,C$ are on $XZ$. How would you prove that $B$ is between the points $A$ and $C$, i.e. $A \ast B \ast C$? I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

$YC$ is the shortest distance between $Y$ and the line $XZ$.

suppose $\hat X \gt \hat Z$ then $A$ and $B$ lie between $C$ and $Z$

using the sine rule in the two triangles $YXA$ and $YAZ$ we can see  that:

$$
\frac{\sin \hat{XYA}}{\sin \hat{AYZ}} = \frac{\sin \hat{ZXY}}{\sin \hat{XZY}} \gt 1
$$
which is the result you require

Comment: You lost me completely. Where is the $M$ coming from and why do you have symbols over $X$ and $Z$

Comment: sorry i've got the wrong letters. i'll try an edit. the $\hat{XYM}$ just means the angle subtended at $Y$ by $XM$ etc.

Comment: I dont suppose there is a way to do this without using the sine rule is there.

Comment: the sine rule merely expresses a consequence of the similarity of the right-angled triangles $XYC$ and $YZC$ so you can "cut out the middle-man"